# Initializing a struct and a pointer

Tags: c, struct

So I know how to declare a struct described as such:

```
struct type_t {
    int ha;
    int ja;
    int ka;
};
```

Then to initialise it:

```
struct type_t[10];
```

How about when I am faced with such a structure:

```
struct type_t {
    int ha;
    int ja;
    int ka;
} *type_tlist = NULL;
```

Would I go ahead and just use `*type_tlist` in my main code?

Thanks in advance guys!!

Comment: "*I know how to initialise a struct*" are you sure?

Comment: You initialized to NULL already ... What's your question?

Comment: So its already declared? My bad, mixing up of language

Comment: Then go and correctly translate your question, please!

Comment: This `struct * type_t;`won't even compile. Also this `struct * type_tlist;` won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say we have this struct:

```
struct type_t {
    int ha;
    int ja;
    int ka; };
```

This is the *definition* of `struct type_t`.

You can declare variables of type `struct type_t` as follows:

```
struct type_t a;
```

Or arrays:

```
struct type_t b[10];
```

Those 2 constructs declares some variables that you can use right away. You can declare pointers having `struct type_t` as a type:

```
struct type_t *c;
```

but in order to access members from them, you need to allocate some memory for them:

```
struct type_t *c = malloc(sizeof(struct type_t));
```

Note that when having a variable (like a or b[2]), you access its members using the dot operator:

```
a.ha = 3;
```

for example. But when having a pointer, you access its members using -> operator:

```
c -> ha = 3;
```

You may assign `NULL` value to a pointer:

```
c = NULL;
```

but you may not access its members until you allocate some memory for it.

I tried to give you a glimpse about working with structs but I would suggest you reading a C book (or at least the chapter about structs and/or pointers).

Comment: I understood all of that, I have just never seen the concept of struct bla {...} *blalist=NULL; that's all

Comment: That is just a pointer declaration and an initialization with NULL, so it does not have a garbage value (this can be useful to test if that pointer points to an allocated memory area or not, i.e. if it is safe to access it).

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
struct type_t {
        int ha;
        int ja;
        int ka;
};

typedef type_t* type_tlist;
```

you can then initialize a pointer to the struct like this.

```
type_tlist x = malloc(sizeof(type_t));
```

if you don't want to use typedef, you can do it like this.

```
struct type_t* x = malloc(sizeof(type_t));
```

now for using the elements of the struct

you can use either -> operator or complicate it by using the . operator the ff. code does the same thing.

```
x -> ha = 1;
(*x).ha = 1;
```

note that these equivalent:

```
array[0] == *(array + 0)
```

so you dont need to use the -> operator if the struct is in an array. you can use the dot without the reference operator '*'